# Invertibility of 2 by 2 continuous maps

Tags: analysis, continuity, inverse-function

This should be a simple question, but I've no idea about a strict proof.

Consider a $2\times2$ map $(x,y)\mapsto(f(x,y),g(x,y))$, where
$f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ and $g:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$
are both continuous (sufficiently smooth, if needed) functions.
If the Jacobian matrix of this map is invertible, then the map
is locally invertible, which is a result of the inverse function theorem.
However, there may be some looser conditions for such an invertibility.

Suppose that in a neighborhood of $(x^*,y^*)=(0,0)$, the function
$f>0$ to one side of the nullcline of $f$ and $f<0$ to the other side,
and the function $g>0$ to one side of the nullcline of $g$ and $g<0$
to the other; moreover, the two nullclines of $f$ and $g$ intersect
at $(0,0)$, transversally.

Does it guarantee that the map $(x,y)\mapsto(f,g)$ is an invertible one?

I believe this is true, but still wonders how to prove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $h(x) = \begin{cases} x^2 & x \ge 0 \\ -x^2 & x < 0 \end{cases}$.

Let $q(x) = \begin{cases} \sin \frac{1}{x} & x \ne 0 \\ 0 & x = 0 \end{cases}$.

Then 
I believe that 
$$
k(x) = (xq(x) + x) + h(x)
$$
is strictly positive to the right of $0$, and strictly negative to the left of $0$, but is not invertible in any neighborhood of $0$.

Letting $f(x, y) = k(x); g(x, y) = y$, the map $(x, y) \to (f(x, y), g(x, y))$ is not invertible in any neighborhood of $(0,0)$, despite satisfying your conditions.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much for your counterexample. But is it possible to strengthen the assumptions to make it true? For example, although the function $k(x)$ is continuous, it is not smooth at $x=0$. Is it possible to strengthen the smoothness of $f$ and $g$ to make the statement true?

Comment: That's a separate question, and one on which I have no real insight, except to say that the Inverse Function Theorem is widely used and taught, which suggests to me that it's at the sweet-spot for this kid of thing. It might be that a function that satisfied a sufficiently tight Lipshitz condition would also work, but I wouldn't bet on it. By the way, mutating questions is considered bad form here at MSE. If an answer leads you to a new question...ask a new question. No one will mind.

Comment: Well, thank you for reminding. I originally thought that asking many related questions separately is bad....